# How can I send my requestdispatcher to two different jsp pages path?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, javabeans

I have made a registration form with the use of JSP, beans and JDBC (MVC)

In my servlet, I have the following code..

```
        if ("editRegister".equalsIgnoreCase(action)) {
        StudentBean user = new StudentBean();

     user.setName(Name);
     user.setStudID(ID);
     user.setCourse(Course);
     user.setEmail(Email);
            db.addRecord(Name, ID, Name, Email);
             set the result into the attribute
            request.setAttribute("StudentBean", user);
            RequestDispatcher rd;
            rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/DisplayRegistry.jsp");
            rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/UpdateRegistry.jsp");
            rd.forward(request, response);
```

Basically, i want to send my requestDispatcher to two jsp pages so that I can display another form with predefined values inside the form.

e.g.

```
<jsp:useBean id="StudentBean" scope="request" class="ict.bean.StudentBean"/>


 <% String email = StudentBean.getEmail() != null ? StudentBean.getEmail() : ""; %>
 <form method="get" action="updateregistry">
 <input type="text" name="email" maxlength="10" size="15" value="<%=email%>">
 </form>
```

However, the problem is it displays null instead of the value as the requestDispatcher is only sent to one path.

Comment: So you want to forward two views to the client. It doesn't make any sense. Don't call `PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();` after calling `rd.forward(request, response);`

Comment: what you want to achieve. Explain a bit more.

Comment: I have a registration form that accepts inputs from the users and save it into the database. Now i want to create another form which can update the previous registration form and i want the previous inputs to show inside the text fields so users can update

Comment: but it is showing null inside the input fields instead of values from previous input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your practice of having two forwards makes no sense

```
rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/DisplayRegistry.jsp");
rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/UpdateRegistry.jsp")
```

Instead you can set the value to the `session` , so that you can access it in both the pages (throughout the application session).

so ,

```
HttpSession session=request.getSession(false);
session.setAttribute("StudentBean", user);
```

You can get the values from the session and have a single request dispatcher

Hope this helps !!